# How do the water molecules in copper sulphate solution help to behave as a paramagnet?(compared with pure copper)

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, magnetic-moment

The component of magnetic moment parallel to the applied B is

$\mu=-g_s\mu_Bm_S-g_L\mu_Bm_L$

if it is orbitally quenched then the $m_L$ averages to 0, and this is for non-central field.

Is the copper sulphate more paramagnetic because the field experienced by the outer electrons on a copper atom looks more central?(leading to a higher mean induced magnetic moment)

I can't seem to find a good argument for this.

Comment: Do refrain from saying "$\text{H}_2\text{O}$ atoms", you will look highly unprofessional if you do so.

Comment: oops, i was in a rush :P